# When should we use SWIFT versus FIX?

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, fix

I've read documents that claim that SWIFT and FIX are **not competing protocols** for financial transactions and messaging. And yet, **I have not come across a clear articulation of when to use SWIFT versus FIX**. For example, I know that FIX can be used for most **trading activities**, e.g. getting a quote, placing an order, canceling an order, getting settlement instructions, managing positions, etc. And I was under the impression that SWIFT is primary for accomplishing electronic wire transfers of money between financial institutions, e.g. as part of the **trade settlement process**. However, now I'm told that SWIFT can also be used to handle rolls and closeouts. Am I right in thinking that there's a significant overlap in terms of the domains covered by the two protocols? Would anyone care to take a crack at clarifying?

Comment: These is nice work of a quant friend, from London, http://fix8.org

Answer (score 4):

SWIFT is actually not a standard per se; rather, it's an organization that operates a proprietary exchange network that utilizes a set of ISO messaging standards.

FIX is a non-proprietary set of messaging standards with no underlying network specified.

There is certainly overlap between the two, and there has been [work to co-align](http://www.londonmarketsystems.com/iso20022.pdf) these standards. I would say the choice between them would be made more on the transport requirements (e.g. SWIFT for a centralized guaranteed delivery) and on the fringes where they don't overlap.

A couple salient threads from the FIX website:

- http://www.fixprotocol.org/discuss/read/46f5a06f
- http://www.fixprotocol.org/discuss/read/53a3fa9b

Answer (score 1):

FIX is frequently used for order entry traffic (new order, amend order, cancel order) and occasionally used for delivering market data when latency and performance are not critical.  (FIX/FAST is quite different, that is an encoding that CME and others use to compress price feed information.)

If you are entering orders (either to a broker or directly to an exchange), FIX is a good choice, and is often your only choice.

Answer (score -2):

SWIFT messages are expensive where as FIX is totally free.

Comment: That's not a fair comparison as SWIFT is an organisation and FIX is a message format.

Answer (score -2):

SWIFT are proprietary and easy to use for all the firms as 98%+ world wide coverage they have.